# How can I tell if I have successfully registered for voting on Catalyst proposals?

Tags: catalyst

My PC crashed while registering for voting in Daedalus.

How can I check to confirm that I have already registered to vote.  Must I just go through the process again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to re-register.

However, at the moment of writing this post, there are no current Catalyst project registrations, are you sure you are just not using an older version of Daedalus?

Comment: I had the problem in the last voting round and wondered if there was a better answer than what I did (re-register).

Comment: Sadly no, the Catalyst voting application and its integration into the blockchain is still pretty raw.